# Using PreparedStatment for Table Update in Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I have been working on this code with a prepared statement , But it gives me a syntax error, and i cannot seem to understand my mistake.

```
pr1=con.prepareStatement("Update  printers set Current Job = ? where printers.PNo = ? ");
            pstmt.setInt(1, JObj.retJobno());
            pstmt.setInt(2, mno);
            pr1.executeUpdate();
```

The error it give is :

> An Exception was caught java.sql.SQLException: [MySQL][ODBC 5.3(a) Driver][mysqld-5.6.19]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Job = ? where printers.PNo = ?' at line 1

Can someone please help me figure this out?

Comment: you have a space between "current" and "job".  Column names can't have spaces.

Comment: Is the column `Current Job` with a blank inside? I think there is a underscore (_) missing?

Comment: @MK It is possible, but if you have a blank inside you have to write the namè enclosed with `

Comment: @Jens sure, but he doesn't have quotes, and it is a bad practice to have spaces in columns anyways.

Comment: @MK I aggree, that is bad practice. But it is possible.

Comment: the column name is correct, but i'll try changing it to Current_Job.

Comment: It now gives this error :SQLBindParameter not used for all parameters

Comment: @KartavyaKhanna you create a statement with the name `pr1`but set the parameter for a statement `pstmt`. please change `pstmt` to `pr1`

Answer (score 0):

First you have a blank in you column name, so you have to add quotes arround the column name or rename it to `Current_Job`

second: 
you create a statement with the name `pr1` but set the parameter for a statement `pstmt`. please change `pstmt` to `pr1`

Comment: @KartavyaKhanna I have added my comments as an answer. Feel free to upvote or accept it if it has helped.